# assigning selected="selected" to dynamic option list

Tags: jquery, dynamic, html-select

In an "edit article" page i have a select list which displays author first and last name, as well as authorId as the value. As well as the article context and headline and so on (fetched with a different method) - though this method also holds the authorId of the specific article.

I need to have the Author of the Article selected in the option list, instead of it defaulting to the first option in the select list.

what i have:

```
echo'<select id="selectAuthor" value="' . $row['AuthorID'] . '"
class="edit_margin" name="author" title="Select the Article Author">';
                //loop through author names in option list $authors_name

                foreach($authors_name as $nameRow){
                    
                    echo'<option class="authorId" value = "' . $nameRow['AuthorID'] . '">'. $nameRow['FirstName'].'
 '.$nameRow['LastName'] .'</option>';
                }
 
                echo'</select>';
```

and the jquery:

```
 var currID = ('#selectAuthor').val();
         
        if(('.authorId').val() == currID){
               $('.authorId').addClass('new_class')
               $('.new_class').prop('selected',true);  
        }
```

OR

```
 var currID = ('#selectAuthor').val();
         
         if($("select option[value=currID]").attr('selected','selected'));
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I hope what I am trying to do is clear.
Thanks in advance

I have simplified it with just regular input and checked it in jsfiddle.net
here is the HTML

```
 <select id="selectAuthor" value="1" class="edit_margin" name="author"
 title="Select the Article Author">';
  
                     
     <option value = "2">Name val 2</option>
     <option value = "5">Name val 5</option>
     <option value = "1">Name val 1</option>
 
 </select>
```

and here is the jquery

```
 var currID = $('#selectAuthor').val();
          if($("select option[value='+currID+']").prop('selected',true));​
```

and even then it doesn't apply selected="selected" to option with value="1"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you don't just add the `selected` in your server code. As far as your jQuery you have several issues.

First, you have syntax problems which should be throwing errors in your browser console. Simply looking at console would have saved you this step

```
var currID = ('#selectAuthor').val();
```

Should be:

```
var currID = $('#selectAuthor').val();
```

Next syntax problem is in second version when you pass `currID` into the string, you are adding it as string text, not as a variable concatenated into the string.

```
if( $("select option[value='+currID+']").attr('selected','selected'));
```

However this is still a problem because you are setting the `attr` not `getting it. Use`prop` method instead an it will retuen a boolean

```
 if( $("select option[value='+currID+']").prop('selected'));
```

The problem with the first version is:

```
  if(('.authorId').val() == currID)
```

Syntax again ( use a browser console!!!) ...missing `$`. Even with the proper syntax you can't check all of the values in one `if` on a collection of elements. It will only return the value of the first one. It's like asking for a single  phone number for 20 different people. You either have to loop over all of the collection using `each()` method and check each one with your `if` or use `filter()`

```
 $('.authorId').filter(function(){
       return this.value == currID;
 }).prop('selected',true)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @charlietfl, I fixed the code accordingly, it didn't work, and it wouldn't be anything to do with your answer - I'm sure i'm just not doing it right, I'd like to try doing it in my server code as you suggested - could you help me out? As you can see I'm really new at this.

Comment: must check for errors!! That is critical step #1 always. Put some sample html and your code into a demo in jsfiddle.net